# Passing string from second view controller to first controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

I am trying to send string from Second VC to First VC. I have assigned delegate to first VC and given protocol in second VC but I don't see the method in First VC is being called when Second VC sends some data.

Code

**First VC**

***FirstViewController.h***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <cellDelegate>

@end
```

***FirstViewController.m***

```
- (void)printString:(NSString *)string{
    NSLog(@"Received string: %@",string);
}
```

***SecondViewController.h***

```
@protocol cellDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)printString:(NSString *)string{
@end

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <cellDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

***SecondViewController.m***

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(printString:)]) {
            [self.delegate printString:@"arrow"]];
        }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you assign a value to the `delegate` property of `SecondViewController`?

Comment: @rmaddy Do you mean string parameter? yes I did..! If your talking about something else then No, I didn't.

Comment: No, I'm talking about the `delegate` property. If you don't set it, you can't call the `printString:` method on it.

Comment: I didn't understand @rmaddy can you please explain me what to do & why ..?

Comment: Do you not know what your own `delegate` property is in your `SecondViewController`? You need to assign it a value.

Comment: @rmaddy I do know the property but what value do you want me to assign to it ?

Comment: Given what you wish to, it needs to be a reference to the first view controller.

Comment: Yor Can use Delegate or NSNotificationCenter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to do

```
SecondViewcontroller *vc;

vc.delegate=self;
```

On first view controller

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just forgot to assign your secondViewController.delegate to self.

1- In first viewController, before pushing secondViewController, with that SecondViewController instance do:

```
secondViewController.delegate = self;
```

I can not comment, so if this does not work out just let me know or share more code.

Answer (score 1):

When you navigate from one VC to Second VC you can set the delegate.

```
SecondViewcontroller *secondVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewcontroller"];
secondVC.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
```

This code writes on FirstViewController. Hope it helps you.